# go to matching brace in non-java files in intellij

Tags: intellij-idea

In IntelliJ (version 9), in a java file, I can go to the matching brace or parentheses by pressing **ctrl-]** or **ctrl-[**.  However, for whatever reason, this only works when I'm in a java file.  How do I find the matching brace when I'm in some other kind of file (for example a json file or html file)?

Comment: FYI: in IntelliJ 12, Ctrl-[ and Ctrl-] work in Javascript and JSON files at the least, and probably in other file types as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not possible right now, I've submitted a new request for this feature:
http://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issue/IDEA-58341

Please vote.